# convergence of sum of $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(k^3+1)}-k}{\ln(k)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The question is the convergence of $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(k^3+1)}-k}{\ln(k)}$$
I know that $\left\{\frac{1}{\ln(k)} \right\}_{k=2}^{\infty }$ is decreasing to $0$,
so the series converge if  $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\sqrt[3]{(k^3+1)}-k$  bounded.
But I'm stuck at proving that.
So I tried to prove the series $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\sqrt[3]{(k^3+1)}-k$ converge but also stuck by using ratio test and root test.
Is my method wrong?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{k\to\infty}k^2(\sqrt[3]{k^3+1}-k) = \frac13$.

Comment: Okay I get it , but how can this help me?

Comment: When $k$ is large enough, the numerator behaves like $\frac1{3k^2}$ :-)

Comment: Oh, so I can use limit comparison test , let $a_{k}$ = $\sqrt[3]{k^{3}+1}-k$ and  $b_{k}$ =$\frac{1}{k^{2}} $,so that $ \lim_{k \to \infty } \frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}}=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: That particular choice of $b_k$ would prove $\sum_{k\ge2}a_k$ converges, but you want to prove $\sum_{k\ge2}\frac{a_k}{\ln k}$ converges, which is a corollary (or you could instead use $b_k=\frac{1}{k^2\ln k}$).

Comment: @J.G. Yeah, choosing $b_{k}$ as $\frac{1}{k^{2}\ln(k)}$ would be clearer. Thanks

Comment: @MathMagician: Tall things in titles are [discouraged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730).